# Is there any way to amplify matplotlib graph without multiplying the all data points in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization

I am currently working with data points and using python matplotlib for visualization. Depending on the values on my graph, it becomes hard to see some of the plots. It is because let's say, one plot is fluctuating around 10000 (big) and the other is 10(small). When I try to visualize them, I am only able to see the bigger one because smaller one becomes line. I added a Slider to amplify smaller one like;

```
axamp = plt.axes([1,1,1,1], facecolor=axcolor)
samp = Slider(axamp, 'Amp', 0.1, 10.0)

def update(val):
    amp = samp.val
    l.set_ydata([i*amp for i in Data])
    plt.draw()
```

Basically, it gets the value from slider and multiplies each data by it. However, the process takes too much time and visualization becomes choppy because I have 500.000 data point. Is there any way that I can visually amplify my data in matplotlib ?

thanks in advance,

Comment: A logarithmic axis is useful for visualizing data that are of very different magnitudes. Have you tried that?

Comment: yes, I have tried it but did not work.

Comment: Maybe it would work to plot the data on different axes entirely? You can share the same x-axis, for example, but have independent y-axes. Does that make sense?

Comment: If scaling the data using some kind of widget is really the approach you need, the speed will definitely be an issue with `matplotlib`, especially with large datasets. Other libraries, like [`pyqtgraph`](http://pyqtgraph.org) are built to specifically address this issue.

Comment: @bnaecker yes, and I think what I am doing is exactly what you said. The problem is, the order of my different plots are changing so, the big one varies from 1000 to 100000 while small one from 10-1000. I do not want to calcluate the y axis amplification every time, thats why I added a slider to adjust them quickly. I wonder how can I easily amplify it. Because its pretty easy to zoom in or zoom out any picture which has a way more data points than my dataset.

Comment: One quick speed win would be to avoid using the list comprehension. The data is an `ndarray`, so just do `l.set_data(l.get_data() * amp)`.

Comment: @bnaecker thank you for your suggestion but it did not happen smoothly. It works too though

Comment: Another suggestion would be to change the axis limits, rather than modifying the data. It may be slightly faster. Without more details about your data, code, and goals, it's hard to say what else may work.